# How to append tuple to sub-sub-list?

Tags: python, append

Suppose I have this data format

```
thingy=[[[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]],[[(-1,-2),(-3,-4)],[(-5,-6),(-7,-8)]]]
```

and I want to append (9,9) to each sub-sub-list so as to have:

```
thingy_2=[[[(1,2),(3,4),(9,9)],[(5,6),(7,8),(9,9)]],[[(-1,-2),(-3,-4),(9,9)],[(-5,-6),(-7,-8),(9,9)]]]
```

Is there any way to do something like the following:

```
thingy_2=[[i for i in j].append((9,9)) for j in thingy] #this doesn't work though
```

I know that if I do:

```
[[i.append((9,9)) for i in j] for j in thingy]
```

This will append (9,9) to the thingy list but won't help me create a new list.

```
thingy_2=[[i.append((9,9)) for i in j] for j in thingy]
"""
In [302]: thingy_2
Out[301]: [[None, None], [None, None]]
""""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append()` carries out the operation on the original `list`, and then `return`s the value `None`. You need to add, or `extend`, the `list`s. For example, `[1,2] + [3,4]` is `[1,2,3,4]`.

```
>>> thingy=[[[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]],[[(-1,-2),(-3,-4)],[(-5,-6),(-7,-8)]]]
>>> thingy_2 = [[l + [(9,9)] for l in s] for s in thingy]
>>> thingy_2
[[[(1, 2), (3, 4), (9, 9)], [(5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 9)]], [[(-1, -2), (-3, -4), (9, 9)], [(-5, -6), (-7, -8), (9, 9)]]]
```